# Выпуклый и...

Tags: лингвистика

Простите, пожалуйста, за глупый вопрос, но мне всегда было интересно, почему бывает "выпуклый", но не бывает "впуклого"?))

Comment: Зато бывает вогнутый)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По Фасмеру, ПУК происходит от праслав. формы *pǫkъ, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. пукъ, укр., белор. пук, чешск., словацк. рuk «росток, почка», польск. рęk «пук», рąk «почка», в.-луж. pukawc «вид гвоздики с лопающимся цветком», н.-луж. рuk «рассыпание при растрескивании». Неотделимо от пу́кать «лопаться», слова, возм., звукоподражательного происхождения. Кроме того,* pǫkъ сравнивают с нов.-перс. раng «гроздь фиников», а также с лат. pānus «нарыв; пучок проса» (возм., из *panknos).

Даль даёт нам прилагательное пуклый, выпуклый - горбом, коробом, раздутый. Пучить, выпучивать что, выпялить, вздымать, вздувать или горбить, коробить. Живот пучит, дует.  Водой лед пучит. Не пучь живота, не выставляй. Пучить глаза, пялить, таращить.

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004: пук (связка). Искон. Того же корня, что пукать «трескаться, лопаться» со звуком «пук». Пук получил название по сходству с распустившимся цветком. См. пучить. 
http://enc-dic.com/dal/Puk-34522/

Следовательно, выпуклый - раздутый, а антонимом будет сдутый, спавший, опавший, ВПАЛЫЙ, (если раздутый опадет до вмятины), вогнутый. Зачем образовывать "Впуклый, спуклый" , если антонимов и так хватает? А может, и было такое слово, но исчезло, мы не знаем,  примеров "исчезания" избыточных, лишних  слов хватает.

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, антонимом к **выпуклому** может также служить и **впалый**. Нельзя же только к линзам применять наш сабж? Ну, а *вогнутых животов* не бывает!

> Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого
> ― И я в зените, ― улыбнулась Таня, положила ладони на **выпуклый живот** и погладила его с боков.
>
> Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и магический контрабас (2002)
> Такой уж я уродился, ― сказал Ванька, не без гордости косясь на свой **впалый живот**.

Comment: Вариант :-) Действительно живой вогнутым не бывает... А впалым - да.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что антоним - вогнутый. А вообще, видимо, вопрос сочетаемости корней и приставок.

Comment: Конечно, здесь несочетаемость приставки В- и лексического значение корня. А вот почему можно "втыкать" (вилку в розетку),а  вытыкать нельзя?

Comment: @Ларf вытыкать вполне можно. Правда речь тогда обычно не о вилках и розетках :-) Ну, и вместо "втыкать" можно попробовать использовать гл. "воткнуть" или "вставить"

Comment: Нет, слова вытыкать словари не дают.

Comment: @Ларf, а [Даль][1] дает.

[1]:http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%A2%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC/

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело в значении слов и приставок (вы- - наружу, во- - внутрь):
**ВЫ́ПУКЛЫЙ** -ая, -ое. 1. Имеющий округлую или дугообразную поверхность, **обращённую наружу** (ср. во́гнутый). В-ые стёкла очков. В-ая линза. / В составе названий геометрических фигур. В. многогранник. 2.
dic.academic.ru › Большой толковый словарь русского языка.

**Во́гнутый**. Прил. Имеющий округлую или дугообразную поверхность, **обращенную внутрь**. Ant: выпуклый
dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ефремовой

**Пучиться** -чится; несов. 1. (несов. вспучиться). разг. **Подниматься** **кверху**, **вздуваться**.
dic.academic.ru › Малый академический словарь